# Reading through an HTML file

Tags: html, html-parsing

I have a HTML file on my computer. I need to go through the file and extract only the text from it, which will then need to be sent to an output file. I have tried simple methods, such as regex, but the file is way to complicated to do like that. To demonstrate this, below there is a small part of the file. What would be the best solution to this? Also, what language would be recommended?

```
    src="https://apps.ideal-logic.com/files/public/feb81069e2541cc3_4WTF-
    39PK/small_thumb/no_photo.png" width="100" />
    </div></div></div></div></div></td><td align="left" valign="top"><div 
    id="k1e7e1347a6586e16"><div style="margin-left:10px;position:relative;">
    <div style="position:relative;"><div id="k61d14cb4bd7c9b1d"><div 
    style="position:relative;"><div style="position:relative;"><div 
    id="k2329528aeb074bce"><div style="position:relative;"><div><div 
    class="L"><b>XXXXXXXXX</b></div></div><div></div></div></div><div 
    id="k4e138f7b9a8cda5f"><div style="position:relative;"></div></div><div 
    id="k734a690c6ec3be3d"><div style="position:relative;"><div 
    style="position:relative;"><div id="k3aef25d5470a3761"><div 
    style="position:relative;"></div></div><div id="kfae5ce53de173253"><div 
    style="position:relative;"><div id="k7e5f871a226c6981"><div><div 
    style="position:relative;"></div></div></div></div></div><div 
    id="kc6b05b0b2907cbd6"><div style="margin-
    bottom:10px;position:relative;"><div style="position:relative;"><div 
    id="k99d6d517ae2fec1c"><div style="position:relative;"><div><a 
    href="mailto:XXXXXXXXX">xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com</a></div><div></div></div>
    </div><div id="k59ef038775af95ac"><div style="position:relative;"><div>
    <div></div><div><div><div>XXXXXXXXX (Home)</div></div></div></div>
    </div></div></div></div></div><div id="k95052b8c903214ae"><div 
    style="margin-bottom:10px;position:relative;"><div><div></div><div><div>
    <div><span id="s38113de6">XXXXXXXXX<br/>XXXXXXXXX 
    05482</span></div></div></div></div></div></div><div 
    id="k58ea548276b5da0d"><div style="position:relative;"></div></div><div 
    id="kb869465048bdb63a"><div style="margin-
    bottom:10px;position:relative;">
```

The entire file is like that, and I cannot find a way to strip off the formatting. The X's are there because there are supposed to be important data that shouldn't be publicly revealed.
The end goal of this is to output all of these to a CSV file, so they can be uploaded into an Excel document. Is there a library or tool that is able to do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript/jQuery(Available in node.js in case you need a backend solution)

```
htmlString=`</div></div></div></div></div></td><td align="left" valign="top"><div 
    id="k1e7e1347a6586e16"><div style="margin-left:10px;position:relative;">
    <div style="position:relative;"><div id="k61d14cb4bd7c9b1d"><div 
    style="position:relative;">....`

text = $(htmlString).text()
```

Result:

```
Isabel Abramsaqua847@aol.com

(802) 497-3311 (Home)

610 Wake Robin DriveShelburne, Vermont
```